# C# Managing a file backup

Tags: c#, backup

I've got a small problem that consists in following: In my C# application, I have a function named MakeBackup() which as it says, makes the backup copy of a txt file in my case. My application also saves some information in a file called settings.txt, so when I launch my application, it checks if this file exists, if yes, it asks you to make a backup.
Let's assume that the user has got already the settings.txt file, the application will try to make the backup of that file, and then it will save it's own settings.txt file.
So, my question is, how can I distinguish the generated settings.txt file by my application from the user settings.txt file? The names are equal, but not the content. But comparing the content of both files is not the solution I'm looking for.

I'll try to explain more: let's say the app generates it's own settings.txt, every time I launch the program, it asks me to do a backup, but I'd like to do the backup ONLY with the user settings.txt file, but not the one generated from the program.

Comment: You can't distinguish the two cases if all you're willing to compare is the filename.  Why don't you want to compare or check the content for some distinguishing feature?

Comment: Unfortunately the content is not always the same, so that's why I can't compare it. The only thing I've got in mind is adding some identifier to the app-generated txt file, like a text line which says "// Generated by App //". This way, I can actually distinguish the two files. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little unclear, but if you don't want to change file names then I'd suggest either putting the backup file in a subfolder, named after the date, or having the backup in the application folder and have previous version in subfolders named after the date.

Comment: That's a pretty nice idea, but what do you think of adding a text line "// Generated by ... //" to the app-generated txt file?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. I think it's simpler and a little more organized to use folders. This way you don't need to parse so it's a little more robust (if you ask me). It's a matter of opinion, though.